# How does python typing (or mypy) handle TypeVars that are bound to a Union in isinstance checks?

Tags: python, types, mypy, typing, typechecking

I have the following code:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[str, int])

def a(x: T) -> T:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return x
    return x
```

but mypy (with `--strict`) raises `error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")`.

In my opinion this should be valid, since

1. str -> str
2. subclass(str) -> subclass(str)
3. int -> int
4. subclass(int) -> subclass(int)
5. str | int -> str | int

So either mypy has a bug, or (more likely) my knowledge of TypeVars is not good enough.

Worth noticing:

- I want to have the str -> str, int -> int mapping, so simply using `Union[str, int]` won't work.
- This function is called sometimes with variables of type `Union[str, int]`, so using `TypeVar["T", str, int]` won't work either.

Comment: This does seem like a bug to me, since you're still returning an object of the same `T` type that was passed in.  I'd work around it with `typing.cast` and report the bug at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues.

Comment: mypy behaviour seems odd to me here too, however I'd also say this code has no need of a `TypeVar`. You could just use an alias instead e.g. `StrOrInt = Union[str, int]` and mypy will then pass it: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=9c05215ca21a7a825d00c25244e9fbd8

Comment: I think the problem is that type variables are *invariant* by default, which means that the return value must have type `Union[str, int]`, not a subtype like `str`. (Note that declaring the type variable as covariant won't work, because you can't use covariant types as function *arguments*.)

Comment: (Possibly worth noting that `mypy` accepts this by default; I had to use `--strict` to reproduce the error, at least in 0.941. I'm not sure which specific option that `--strict` enables is the one to trigger the error.)

Comment: `T = TypeVar('T', int, str)` also seems to solve the problem.

Comment: @chepner the function is sometimes called with str | int, so that won't solve my problem.

Comment: @Anentropic I want to keep the str -> str and int -> int mapping if possible.

Comment: I see... you could use `@overload` to do get `str -> str` and `int -> int` typing https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#type-checking-calls-to-overloads ... or just `cast` back to `T`

Comment: @Samwise I have created an issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12800